# Laravel get collection data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, geocode

Below is my array result. I am trying to access the sublocality data but I keep running to an error:

> Can't use object of type as array

I have use `$result[$some_imdex]->subLocality` and this didn't work.

```
array:5 [▼
    0 => GoogleAddress {#204 ▼
    -id: "ChIJGzuDx6X1OxARcJhhmLrPLPs"
    -locationType: "ROOFTOP"
    -resultType: array:1 [▶]
    -formattedAddress: "27b Bolaji Street, Maroko, Lagos, Nigeria"
    -streetAddress: null
    -intersection: null
    -political: "Nigeria"
    -colloquialArea: null
    -ward: null
    -neighborhood: "Maroko"
    -premise: null
    -subpremise: null
    -naturalFeature: null
    -airport: null
    -park: null
    -pointOfInterest: null
    -establishment: null
    -subLocalityLevels: AdminLevelCollection {#205 ▶}
    -coordinates: Coordinates {#207 ▶}
    -bounds: Bounds {#208 ▶}
    -streetNumber: "27b"
    -streetName: "Adewale Kolawole Crescent"
    -subLocality: "Eti-Osa"
    -locality: "Lagos"
    -postalCode: null
    -adminLevels: AdminLevelCollection {#209 ▶}
    -country: Country {#212 ▶}
    -timezone: null
    -providedBy: "google_maps"
  }
  1 => GoogleAddress {#213 ▶}
  2 => GoogleAddress {#221 ▶}
  3 => GoogleAddress {#228 ▶}
  4 => GoogleAddress {#236 ▶}
]
```

Comment: You can turn an array into a collection with collect($array), have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks. 
Nope, I will try that now and see if it will work

Comment: I turn it to collection but I still can't access the "subLocality" data

Comment: And for what index are you getting this error? Is it really 0..4?

Comment: I'm getting this error from Index 0

Comment: The error is saying $result is an object, not an array, which doesn't match up if your dump is of $result.

Comment: @Devon yeah. If I tried doing something like this "dd($new[0]->id)" the error is Cannot access private property

Comment: Actually, I don't think it knows what $result is. There would be an object type after type in "Can't use object of type as array". It would say 'Can't use object of type StdClass as array' or something similar. What does dd($result) look like?

Comment: dd($result) is the same as what I posted but it wraps around Collection.

Collection {#178 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => GoogleAddress {#204 ▼
      -id: "ChIJGzuDx6X1OxARcJhhmLrPLPs"
      -locationType: "ROOFTOP"
      -resultType: array:1 [▶]
      -formattedAddress: "27b Adewale Kolawole Cres, Maroko, Lagos, Nigeria"
      -streetAddress: null
      -intersection: null
      -political: "Nigeria"
      -colloquialArea: null

Comment: Ohhh, it's already a collection. Easy, you have to use collection methods on it. $result->where('id', $some_id)->first()->property_you_want

Comment: Have you tried something like `$result->first()->subLocality` ?

Comment: dump out `gettype($result)`  There's no reason to use collect() here so avoid that code and dump the actual result as per the question.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a collection, you cannot use an array index to get the specific model. You can use collection methods to access that model, IE:

```
$result->where('id', $some_id)->first()->subLocality
```

Comment: could you provide a better answer ?

Comment: You can access collections as arrays because they implement the ArrayAccess interface http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php

Comment: I stand corrected, I've just tried out a few different ways and it seems like it can be accessed using an index. I'm not sure what is causing the problem then.

Answer (score 0):

The object response its wrapped on an array!

So you are tying to access an object inside that array trying to access through index, therfore you get that error.

What you could do: cast array to collection and then map over that collection:

```
collect($results)->filter($result){

    return $result->subLocality === 'some value';

});
```

`filter()` method will filter the collection and return the elemnts that meet the condition.

Or if you want to return some specific data then use `map()`

```
collect($results)->map($result){

    return [ 
            '0'=>$result->subLocality,
            '1'=>$result->someIndex,
         ];
});
```

`map()` will return a transformed array from the given collection. For more read [Laravel Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections)

Answer (score 0):

- `-` private
- `+` public
- `#` protected

You can't access the property you want directly outside the class as its private, not public.

This `GoogleAddress` class which extends `Address` has methods (getters) for accessing all these fields.

```
$addressObject->getSubLocality();
```

Regardless of whether you have a collection or an array or what ever ... you can't access those properties on that class directly.

You also have the option of calling `toArray()` on one of these instances to get an associative array, which perhaps might be easier depending on what you are doing.